# Getting a sum of a list in excel

Tags: excel

I have an excel cell that has a value like this:

```
[194, 294, 294, 294]
```

I am trying to get the sum of this cell which is a value generated with python in a list structure.

I have not found any questions on this problem.
I tried `=SUM(A2)` but for some reason, it returns `0` instead of a an error which I expected.

Comment: `SUM()` will ignore all text-values in the summation, so no error will be thrown. What you want to try here is to "split" the value, possibly through `FILTERXML()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try-

```
=SUM(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"[",""),"]",""),", ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"))
```

[image]

Comment: Or: `=SUM(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(MID(A2,2,LEN(A2)-2),",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"))`

Comment: Thank you, could it be that in the online version of excel `FILTERXML` is not a valid function? Because the same code works on the offline version, but not on the online version of excel.

Comment: @JvdV This will work for this particular case and numbers are fixed length. If numbers are variable lengths then it will fail.

Comment: @JonasPalačionis Online version do not have `FILTERXML()`. If it is google sheet then you can use `SPLIT()` function.

Comment: @Harun24HR, can you share an example where it would fail for demonstration purposes?

Comment: @JvdV Sorry! I didn't notice formula carefully. If format is same then any length numbers will work.